# Seam 2 - custom scopes

Tags: java, seam

I do not plan on using Weld, but still would like to have custom scopes for components.

I am using Seam in a non-conventional way such that I would like to have control over contexts / scopes.  I have background jobs / tasks that call other services.  This is somewhat similar to the event / method scope, but I would like to control my own (naming, when it starts, ends, etc.).

Is this possible in Seam 2, or do I have to wait till Seam 3?

Comment: @Walter White As far as i know, Seam 2.x does not provide this sort of funcionality. But if you get any resource, share it with us.

Comment: I am migrating towards CDI and then Seam 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have migrated to CDI / Weld.  I originally didn't want to migrate as I thought Seam 3 would be my answer, but Seam 3 will be on top of CDI / Weld providing additional functionality.  CDI / Weld is exactly what I want and no learning curve.

Walter